# Как написать цикл на js, чтобы выполнить его через консоль?

Tags: javascript, dom, for

Всем привет!

Есть задача, на странице есть элемент, по которому я могу кликнуть написав команду в консоли браузера

```
document.querySelector(".icon_remove").click();
```

После этого появляется ещё один элемент, по которому я также могу успешно кликнуть

```
document.querySelector(".button_noround").click();
```

Затем снова появляется первый элемент

То есть я пишу и выполняю эти команды по отдельности, но циклом сделать это не получается:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
  let currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}
for (i = 0; 10; i++) {
  document.querySelector(".icon_remove").click();
  sleep(500);
  document.querySelector(".button_noround").click();
  sleep(500);
}; // задержка в 1 секунду
```

Подскажите, как скорректировать цикл

Пробовал так же записать цикл так:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {   const date = Date.now();   let currentDate = null;   do {your text` currentDate = Date.now(); } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds); } let removeButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".icon_remove"); let noroundButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".button_noround");

for (let i = 0; i < removeButtons.length && i < noroundButtons.length; i++) { removeButtons[i].click(); sleep(1000); noroundButtons[i].click();

if (i < removeButtons.length - 1 && i < noroundButtons.length - 1) { removeButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".icon_remove"); noroundButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".button_noround"); } }`
```

Консоль по-прежнему пишет "undefined"

Comment: Твой `sleep` не совсем sleep... Т.е. он не прекращает работу твоего скрипта - он его выполняет. Т.о. у другого скрипта нет шансов начать менять ДОМ и добавлять в него элементы, которые ты хотел далее использовать... Вот `setTimeout()` тут подошел бы.

Comment: `sleep` должна быть асинхронной функцией и возвращать `Promise` (промис должен резолвиться после цикла), а перед каждым использованием вы должны писать `await`, чтобы получилось вот так: `await sleep(n);`.

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите, как скорректировать цикл

Поскольку ТС не предоставил исходный пример с кликабельными элементами, я сделал некую модель самостоятельно, т.с. для иллюстрации процесса.

Мой пример поможет понять как сделать один из вариантов "кликанья" по ключевым элементам, дав им возможность отработать свои синхронные скрипты.

Если же скрипты будут асинхронные - вполне возможно что таймаута в 1с им может и не хватить. Тогда нужно будет использовать другие механизмы JS, которые позволяют следить за изменениями в ДОМ...

```js
/* подготовительные работы */

const ot = document.querySelector("#test")
ot.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const ob = e.target.closest('.button_noround')
  if (!ob) return
  let o = document.createElement('p')
  o.textContent = new Date().toISOString()
  ot.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', o)
})

document.querySelector(".icon_remove").addEventListener('click', _ => {
  const o = document.createElement('button')
  o.classList.add('button_noround')
  o.textContent = 'button_noround ' + new Date().toISOString()
  ot.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', o)
})

/* окончание подготовительных работ */

/* собственно тест */

setTimeout(function test() {
  test.count = test.count ?? 0
  if (++test.count > 5) return
  document.querySelector(".icon_remove").click()
  setTimeout(_ => {
    document.querySelector(".button_noround").click()
    setTimeout(test, 1000)
  }, 1000)
}, 1000)
```

```html
<div id='test'>
  <button class='icon_remove'>icon_remove</button>
</div>
```